# Why is sp_Blitz executing for more than 5 hours

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sp-blitz

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMUbL.png)
I am running sp_Blitz on my SQL Server 2014 with 93 databases. It has been running for more than 5 hours and still won't complete. I am able to run sp_BlitzWho,sp_BlitzIndex,sp_BlitzFirst and sp_Blitzbackup and they all take about 2-3 minutes to complete.

I wonder why is it (sp_Blitz) running too long and still not providing any results.

Comment: Since you can run sp_BlitzWho, perhaps you can determine which query it's stuck on, and use the skip checks functionality to pass over that one?

Answer (score 4):

In your screenshot, you're running sp_WhoIsActive. You can click on the query text in blue:

[image]

And that'll tell you which query is running slow, and might give you some insight into why. You can also read the documentation, which mentions to try @CheckUserDatabaseObjects = 0 as a parameter to go faster.